# Construct order-type in Z

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

My question is that how to construct an ordered set which has order-type as large as possible in [Zermelo set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) **Z**? For instance, how to construct $\epsilon_0$ or even some uncountable order-type in **Z**?

I know basic result about ordinals and we couldn't construct $\omega + \omega$ in **Z** but rather an ordered set isomorphic to it. I'm not very sure if this question is related to Hartogs numbers, since the construction of Hartogs numbers needs **ZF** rather than **Z**.

This question is related to another question I asked: [The different between **Z** and **ZF**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2319303/301545)

Comment: Until the end of the second paragraph I was confused and thought tthat **Z** stood for $\Bbb Z$ and not for $\mathsf{Z}$ ...

Comment: A somewhat related question and answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402271/von-neumann-universe-in-zc.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303064/

Comment: @EricWofsey I'd clarify to say that *your answer*, specifically, is relevant to the OP; I think the question as a whole might not be.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Good point.  I've modified the link to go straight to the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can do much better than $\epsilon_0$ in Z - we can construct *uncountable well-ordered sets*! The key observation is that, while building long *ordinals* uses Replacement, building long *well-ordered sets* is really a job for just Powerset and Separation.

It's a good exercise to verify the following argument:

- Z proves that the set $\mathcal{R}$ of all binary relations on $\omega$ exists.
- Z then proves that the subset $\mathcal{W}\subseteq\mathcal{R}$ of all *well-founded* binary relations on $\omega$ exists.
- Z then proves that the set $\mathcal{W}'$ of *equivalence classes* of elements of $\mathcal{W}'$ under the relation "are order-isomorphic" exists.
- Finally, Z proves that the relation $\mathcal{L}\subseteq\mathcal{W}'\times\mathcal{W}'$ given by "is longer than" exists.

But now the pair $\mathfrak{O}=(\mathcal{W}', \mathcal{L})$ is an uncountable well-ordered set, provably in Z (by the usual argument). So we have:

> Even though the *ordinal* $\omega_1$ doesn't provably exist in Z, we can emulate its construction by working with sets of natural numbers.

We can go much further: the above argument shows that for any set $A$, we can form the well-order $Ord(A)$ of ordertypes of well-ordered relations on subsets of $A$. In particular, we can apply this to $\mathfrak{O}$ to build a version of $\omega_2$, and so on. In fact, we can prove in Z that for every $n$, a version of $\omega_n$ exists (of course we have to phrase this rather carefully); conversely, it's consistent with Z that every well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to a subset of one of these versions, so in a sense Z "reaches up to" the ordinal $\omega_\omega$.

(Towards interpreting the previous sentence, it's a good exercise to show that in $(V_{\omega+\omega})^L$, the smallest transitive model of Z, the lengths of the well-ordered sets are exactly the ordinals $<\omega_\omega^L$. If you're not familiar with the "[stuff]$^L$" notation, then work with $V_{\omega+\omega}$ instead and assume GCH.)

Comment: I can't see the reason of why $\omega_\omega$ is reachable(you only describe that $\omega_n$ is reachable). Even so, it is enough to solve my question...

Comment: @MinghuiOuyang $\omega_\omega$ is **not** reachable - we can reach *up to* it (that is, we can reach everything below it) but we can't reach it itself. I guess that was unclear.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't understand "reach up to" before.

Comment: @MinghuiOuyang I noticed you un-accepted this answer - may I ask what further questions you have?

Comment: Oh... Misoperation. So sorry.

Comment: Asuming **global choice** why cant we pick a set of size $\aleph_{n}$ for each $n$ in a model without replacement, and apply hartogs lemma? To get $\aleph_{\omega}$ that seems to contradict this answer...